# Where is the ambient temperature sensor located on an Opel / Vauxhall Insignia 2.0 CDTI 2010?

Tags: sensor, opel, temperature

Can anyone offer some guidance in finding the placement of the ambient temperature sensor for an Opel / Vauxhall Insignia 2.0 CDTI 2010?

The sensor seems to be malfunctioning. The value for the outside ambient temperature is either not displayed at all or, when it is displayed, it is giving a false reading of -40 degrees C.

It seems to randomly choose when it does display the value and when it doesn't, but when it does have a reading, the engine is reving at around 1300 at idle (instead of the usual 850-ish) and the AC seems to stop working (because it probably thinks the outside temperature really is -40 C).

Where is this sensor located so I can get a serial number off of it, order a new one and replace it? 
Or at least to check that the cables are properly attached.

On a side note, so as to avoid any future questions, is there any place I can buy a repair / service manual for this vehicle? I am not interested in a hard copy as I would much rather have it in pdf or ebook format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensor is located in the lower front grille, left side (driving direction). The sensor should be visible through the grille raster, there should be only one distinct component
[image]

Comment: Since OPs question is so specific (where is this one exact part on this one car), a more specific answer would be preferred. Could you provide a picture? If not, at least more details as to what the sensor is connected to,  how many/what color wires it may be connected to, or what it looks like? Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Ok... I took a closer look and indeed that seems to be the temp sensor. With a flashlight I could also see behind the sensor a dangling connector so that`s my problem.  The connector for the right fog lamp was also disconnected.

Comment: Do you know of any way to take the sensor out without removing the bumper?